# Laravel connect data on pivot table involving three tables

Tags: laravel

I have the following Models and pivot table:

User:

```
    public function accounts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Account', 'account_role_user', 'user_id', 'account_id');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'account_role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
```

Account

```
public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'account_role_user', 'account_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'account_role_user', 'account_id', 'role_id');
    }
```

Role:

```
   public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'account_role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id');
   }

   public function accounts() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Account', 'account_role_user', 'role_id', 'account_id');
     }
```

`account_role_user`

Cols: `user_id`, `role_id`, `account_id`

A user can belong to many different accounts and have many different roles on different accounts.

So they many belong to an account "Phillies" with role of admin, and they may also belong to an account "Astros" with a role of manager.

It's easy enough to query one relationship like `App\User::find(2)->accounts` or `App\User::find(2)->roles`, but I'm having trouble with the third relationship.

At the moment, I'm just trying to query them all and display on a page.

So I'd like to list the accounts the current user belongs to as well as their role on that account.

---

Edit: Dilip Hirapara provided the following query

```
Account::with('users.roles')->wherehas('users', function($q){
    $q->where('users.id','=', 2);
})->get();
```

The first index of the collection is:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3024
     all: [
       App\Account {#3069
         id: 1,
         company: "astros",
         created_at: "2020-02-25 12:35:06",
         updated_at: "2020-02-25 12:35:06",
         users: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3085
           all: [
             App\User {#3071
               id: 1,
               name: "alex",
               email: "alex@fo.com",
               email_verified_at: null,
               created_at: "2020-02-25 12:35:06",
               updated_at: "2020-02-25 12:35:06",
               pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3083
                 account_id: 1,
                 user_id: 1,
               },
               roles: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3094
                 all: [
                   App\Role {#3096
                     id: 1,
                     level: "owner",
                     created_at: "2020-02-25 12:32:50",
                     updated_at: "2020-02-25 12:32:50",
                     pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3099
                       user_id: 1,
                       role_id: 1,
                     },
                   },
                 ],
               },
             },
             App\User {#3084
               id: 2,
               name: "jeb",
               email: "jebbush@gmail.com",
               email_verified_at: null,
               created_at: "2020-02-25 12:36:57",
               updated_at: "2020-02-25 12:36:57",
               pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3039
                 account_id: 1,
                 user_id: 2,
               },
               roles: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3091
                 all: [
                   App\Role {#3097
                     id: 2,
                     level: "admin",
                     created_at: "2020-02-25 12:32:50",
                     updated_at: "2020-02-25 12:32:50",
                     pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3088
                       user_id: 2,
                       role_id: 2,
                     },
                   },
                   App\Role {#3100
                     id: 3,
                     level: "manager",
                     created_at: "2020-02-25 12:32:50",
                     updated_at: "2020-02-25 12:32:50",
                     pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3090
                       user_id: 2,
                       role_id: 3,
                     },
                   },
                 ],
               },
             },
           ],
         },
       }
```

The data I have in my database is expressed as

`alex@fo.com` (user) is `owner`(role) on `astros`(account)

`jebbush@gmail.com`(user) is `admin`(role) on `astros`(account)

`jebbush@gmail.com`(user) is `manager`(role) on `phillies`(account)

So you will notice the query is getting ALL roles from the user regardless of the account.

So I would like to query accounts showing users and their roles. (roles they have on a specific account)

Also is my model relationship correct? Should `Account` `belongsToMany` `Role`?

Comment: So what is the relation between the `company`, `user` and `role`? can you elaborate? and where is the relation between `user` and `company`? Do you want to company + user and user + roles?

Comment: I was able to answer this from another question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60555602/laravel-how-to-get-column-related-to-another-column-in-pivot-table-3-column-pi/60569007#60569007

Answer (score 1):

As you said the **user** belongsTo **company**

And the use

```
App\User::with('company','role')->whereId(2)->first();
```

By this, you'll get the user with company and roles.

```
App\User::with('accounts.roles')->whereId(2)->first();
```

By this, you'll get the **(user with accounts)** and **(accounts with there roles)** particular that user.

And now if you want to use it as by **Account** model

```
Account::with('users.roles')->wherehas('users', function($q){
    $q->where('id','=', 2);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is setting me in the right direction. Is it possible to group the users with the roles instead of having roles separate? I'd like to query all accounts with users and have roles attached to the users which are inside of accounts

Comment: `I'd like to query all accounts with users and have roles attached to the users` The last query is about that account with users and roles.

Comment: It doesn't quite work how I need it to because this will attach users to an account and show all their roles, but it will show roles that they're not assigned to on the specific account. hard to explain with a comment. I will edit my question at some point and show what I mean.

Comment: select the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I can upvote for helping me, but it doesn't fully answer my question. I edited with what I mean.