# laravel: How to get column related to another column in pivot table (3 column pivot)

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm not sure how to phrase this question, but I need to do the following:

I have a pivot table with three columns `user_id`, `account_id`, `role_id`

So in my database if I have these rows on `account_role_user` (pivot)

```
|---------------------|------------------|-------------
|     account_id      |     user_id      |   role_id  |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------
|          1          |         1        |     1      |
|---------------------|--------------------------------
|          2          |         2        |     1       |
------------------------------------------------------
|          1          |         2        |     3      |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Role - 1 = owner

Role - 3 = manager

What I'm trying to do is get users on a specific account with their specific role. But I'm only able to query things like `App\User::with('accounts.roles')->whereId(2)->first();` which does show the users on an account, but it groups their roles that aren't **specific to the account**.

I only want the users and their roles that are relevant to the account.

If I'm querying account with id of 1 and I want to list users on that account with their role, I should have something like:

`$account = App\Account::find(1)`

`User with ID of 1 has a role id of 1 on the account id of 1`

`User with ID of 2 has a role id of 3 on the account id of 1`

User Model:

```
    public function accounts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Account', 'account_role_user', 'user_id', 'account_id');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'account_role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
```

Account model:

```
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'account_role_user', 'account_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'account_role_user', 'account_id', 'role_id');
    }
```

Role Model:

```
   public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'account_role_user', 'role_id', 'user_id');
   }

   public function accounts() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Account', 'account_role_user', 'role_id', 'account_id');
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to someone's help on Laravel's Discord channel, I figured this out.

On the `Account` Model, I changed the `users()` relation to:

```
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'account_role_user')
        ->using('App\AccountRoleUser')
        ->withPivot('role_id');
    }
```

I created a pivot model called `AccountRoleUser`

```
namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class AccountRoleUser extends Pivot
{
    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
}
```

And on the `User` model, I changed the `accounts()` relation to:

```
    public function accounts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Account::class, 'account_role_user')->withPivot('role_id');
    }
```

Now my query is really succinct and logical:

```
$account = auth()->user()->accounts->where('foo', 'bar')->first();
$users = $account->users;
```

Each User inside the collection has a `pivot` object now coming from the pivot model.

Which means I can now do something like:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
  <p>This is user {{ $user->first_name }} {{ $user->last_name }} with a role of 
   {{$user->pivot->role->description}} 
</p>
@endforeach
```