# Laravel: Find specific pivot value from three-way pivot

Tags: laravel

I previously made this question: [laravel: How to get column related to another column in pivot table (3 column pivot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60555602/laravel-how-to-get-column-related-to-another-column-in-pivot-table-3-column-pi)

Which helped me loop through my three-way pivot and link each User, Account, and Role.

The implementation doesn't concern itself with a specific user or account.

On my app, a single Account can have many users. These users have specific roles on accounts like "owner", "admin", "manager", etc.

I'm creating a policy to determine if a user has permission based on their role on a specific account to perform an action.

I'm playing around with Tinker. So if I grab a user, and do `$user->roles`, it'll output

```
>>> $user->roles
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3226
     all: [
       App\Role {#3250
         id: 1,
         name: "owner",
         manage_billing: 1,
         manage_users: 1,
         close_account: 1,
         created_at: "2020-05-02 12:34:39",
         updated_at: "2020-05-02 12:34:39",
         pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3219
           user_id: 1,
           role_id: 1,
           account_id: 1,
         },
       },
     ],
   }
```

Given that I have an `account_id`, I'd like to check the role on that specific account.

I tried something like:

`$user->roles->wherePivot('account_id', $account->id);`

but the method `wherePivot` doesn't exist on collections.

(the `$account` variable is just `$user->accounts()->first()` in this example)

My Models and relationships are on the question I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what I wanted:

`$user->roles()->wherePivot('account_id', $account->id)->first();`

My mistake was not doing `roles()`